# Powershell and BitLocker - When changing Protectors from Password to TPMandPIN protector are you required to Suspend Powershell and then renable?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, encryption, bitlocker, tpm

I have a Password Encrypted SDD I am moving from an old host (No TPM) to a new one with a TPM installed. I DO (yes do) know my password. I do not want to decrypt and encrypt (I honestly do not want to wait). Am I required to suspend and change the key then resume BitLocker for this? Is it even possible to handle this through Powershell or MUST I use manage-bde? I would like to just put the SSD into the new host. Enter the password. Remove-BitLockerKeyProtector [PasswordProtector], clear keys from TPM, Add-BitLockerKeyProtector [TpmAndPinProtector].
Then create a Recovery Key and store it somewhere (like a USB). Just so everyone knows, I am not on AD. Just trying to do this on my local host. I am trying to learn Powershell scripting, but have not worked CLI with BitLocker before.

```
C:\> Remove-BitlockerKeyProtector -MountPoint "C:" -PasswordProtector $Password
 Initialize-TPM -AllowClear
 Restart-Computer -For Powershell -Delay 15
 Add-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint "C:" -TpmAndPinProtector -Pin 
 C:\>Get-BitLockerVolume | Add-BitLockerKeyProtector -RecoveryKeyPath "F:\Recovery\" -RecoveryKeyProtector
```

Is it really this simple? I mean, when not dealing with AD. I would really not to loose my work before I start. And I am hoping this would not have to decrypt and encrypt the whole drive. Notice I did not use the -usedspaceonly attribute. And as I did not specify the PIN, it should be user entered and saved as a securestring, correct?

Comment: For protecting a secondary drive via TPM AFAIK the system drive also have to be Bitlocker with TPM protected. As you include TPM initialization in your command I assume your system drive is not yet Bitlocker encrypted, correct?

Comment: The SDD is BitLocker Password encrypted without a TPM.  I will be treating this as the primary drive in the new host.  Just using my SSD from the old device.

Comment: The new host does have a TPM.

Comment: I don't think you can directly convert the drive. There may be a chance using an intermediate step using a USB stick protector. But there is still the problem that most likely the SSD is not partitions correctly if it was used as secondary drive before. You still need the UEFI and boot partition where Bitlocker installs all the necessary stuff for booting from the encrypted system drive. I am not sure how all those steps can be performed manually. The common way would be to decrypt the whole drive, add the required partitions, make it bootable and the enable Bitlocker.

Comment: This was the primary drive (bootable).  Will continue to be primary.  No secondary drive in either host.